# Query list of sites to check SSLcertificate compliance with chrome 66

Tags: chrome, ssl

The Quote below is from google chrome 66 release notes:

> ## Deprecations
>
> #### Enable CommonName fallback for local anchors policy
>
> The EnableCommonNameFallbackForLocalAnchors policy was offered to give
>   admins more time to update their local certificates. It removes the
>   ability to allow certificates on sites using a certificate issued by
>   local trust anchors that are missing the subjectAlternativeName
>   extension.
>
> As of Chrome M66, we will be deprecating this policy. If a user
>   running Chrome 66 tries to access a site where the certificate isn't
>   allowed, they will see a warning indicating they can't trust the
>   certificate.

Some of the certificates I am using do not contain the `Subject Alternative Name` extension which now seems to be mandatory.

I am not fan of doing this manually given the amount of certificates i should be checking.

Is there a way to query servers and determine if their certificates have the `Subject Alternative Name` extension or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a script to cycle over you hostnames and use `openssl` to check certificates.

An example in `bash`:

```
for host in host1.example.com host2.example.com host3.example.com ; do
    echo ===== $host =====
    openssl s_client -connect $host:443 < /dev/null 2> /dev/null \
      | openssl x509 -noout -text \
      | grep "Subject Alternative Name" -A2
done
```